# Changing default from e-mail address for system accounts when using sendmail

Tags: linux, email, postfix, sendmail

I would like certain system accounts (`root` and `www-data`) to have the header `From: Example Company <noreply@example.com>` when e-mail is sent using either the `mail` or `sendmail` commands, or from programming languages like PHP (which just uses a sendmail wrapper).

I would prefer not to have to add the `-f` and `-F` options every time I invoke one of these commands. Is there any way to configure this specifically for these accounts?

Operating system is Debian 7.2.

Comment: Are you sure you are using "Sendmail" as your MTA and not postfix or some other drop-in replacement with the name "sendmail" ?

Comment: The MTA is postfix, but the `sendmail` executable is not symlinked to anything.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I ran into this recently.

You can change the address with the generic maps as davidgo mentioned.

In `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

Add this line

```
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
```

And then in `/etc/postfix/generic`
Add the line for the originating email address, and the email address you want it to appear to be from

```
root@system.fqdn noreply@company.com
www-data@system.fqdn noreply@company.com
```

and then run the following postmap command to re-generate the map:

```
 postmap /etc/postfix/generic
```

To make the user appear to be `Example Company` you need to set the GECOS field in `/etc/passwd` for `root` and `www-data` to be `Example Company`

Answer (score 1):

As you are actually using Postfix (The sendmail binary is actually Postfix), You can probably change the from adress this by adding a "[smtp_generic_maps](http://semi-legitimate.com/blog/item/how-to-rewrite-outgoing-address-in-postfix)" file and mapping for the relevant addresses or using [canonical_maps](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#canonical) to do something similar. I don't think you will be able to change the associated account name (ie the part in the square brackets) without massive hoops but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I write here what I made some times to find with **Exim4**

It's apparently simple :

1. For the email rewrite:

   ```
   $ vim /etc/email-addresses

   root: noreply@example.com
   www-data: noreply@example.com
   ```
2. For the fullname rewrite

   ```
   $ vim /etc/passwd

   root:x:0:0:Example Company:/root:/bin/bash
   www-data:x:33:33:Example Company:/var/www:/usr/bin/nologin
   ```